# Unable to parse graphql endpoint

Tags: rust, graphql, serde

I am trying to parse the response to a graphql endpoint using this code:

```rust
extern crate serde_derive;

use gql_client::Client;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct DevActivity {
    pub data: Data,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Data {
    #[serde(rename = "getMetric")]
    pub get_metric: GetMetric,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct GetMetric {
    #[serde(rename = "timeseriesData")]
    pub timeseries_data: Vec<TimeseriesDatum>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct TimeseriesDatum {
    pub datetime: String,
    pub value: i64,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Vars {
    metric: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let query = r#"
    {
        getMetric(metric: "dev_activity") {
          timeseriesData(slug: "ethereum", from: "2020-02-10T07:00:00Z", to: "2020-03-10T07:00:00Z", interval: "1w") {
            datetime
            value
          }
        }
      }
        "#;

    let endpoint = "https://api.santiment.net/graphql";
    let client = Client::new(endpoint);
    let response = client.query::<DevActivity>(query).await.unwrap().unwrap();
    for data in &response.data.get_metric.timeseries_data {
        println!("datetime {}, value {}", data.datetime, data.value)
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: 
GQLClient Error: Failed to parse response: Error("missing field `data`", line: 1, column: 294). The response body is: {"data":{"getMetric":{"timeseriesData":[{"datetime":"2020-02-06T00:00:00Z","value":795.0},{"datetime":"2020-02-13T00:00:00Z","value":1281.0},{"datetime":"2020-02-20T00:00:00Z","value":1115.0},{"datetime":"2020-02-27T00:00:00Z","value":952.0},{"datetime":"2020-03-05T00:00:00Z","value":605.0}]}}}
', src/main.rs:49:61
```

I am unsure what the error is , as the struct I am pssing it to has a `data` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gql_client` crate [appears](https://docs.rs/gql_client/1.0.4/src/gql_client/client.rs.html) to parse the top-level structure (composing of `data` and/or `errors`) on your behalf. Probably because its [part of the graphql spec](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Response-Format) and you shouldn't need to worry about it. So you don't need the `DevActivity` structure at all and simply use `Data`:

```
let response = client.query::<Data>(query).await.unwrap().unwrap();
for data in &response.get_metric.timeseries_data {
    ...
}
```